# Aca-py 0.6.0: INFO Ledger instance not provided error/bug?

Tags: python, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy, hyperledger-aries

i am new to Hyperledger Aries and i can´t figure out what i am doing wrong.

Environment:

- Ubuntu16LTS
- Docker 18.09.7 build 2d0083d
- hyperledger-aries-python version: 0.6.0 (sourcecode)

From the aca-py repo (https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-cloudagent-python i run:

./scripts/run_docker start -e http://host.docker.internal:8000 -it http 0.0.0.0 8000 -ot http --admin 0.0.0.0 11000 --admin-insecure-mode --log-level DEBUG --genesis-url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHempel-esatus/SSI4DE_Genesis/master/pool_transactions_genesis --trace

NOTE: I have tried different pool_genesis_transaction files and tried to pass them in various ways (via URL, via a File located in the docker conainer). It always drops the same or similar Info:

```
2021-03-12 09:48:32,311 aries_cloudagent.config.ledger INFO Ledger instance not provided
2021-03-12 09:48:32,312 aries_cloudagent.core.conductor WARNING No ledger configured
```

Here is the full output:

```
2021-03-12 09:48:31,035 asyncio DEBUG Using selector: EpollSelector
2021-03-12 09:48:31,036 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.out_of_band
2021-03-12 09:48:31,037 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.actionmenu
2021-03-12 09:48:31,038 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.routing
2021-03-12 09:48:31,039 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.discovery
2021-03-12 09:48:31,041 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.introduction
2021-03-12 09:48:31,041 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.problem_report
2021-03-12 09:48:31,042 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.coordinate_mediation
2021-03-12 09:48:31,043 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.present_proof
2021-03-12 09:48:31,044 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.trustping
2021-03-12 09:48:31,045 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.didexchange
2021-03-12 09:48:31,047 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.issue_credential
2021-03-12 09:48:31,048 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.basicmessage
2021-03-12 09:48:31,050 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.protocols.connections
2021-03-12 09:48:31,051 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.holder
2021-03-12 09:48:31,057 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.ledger
2021-03-12 09:48:31,072 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.messaging.credential_definitions
2021-03-12 09:48:31,085 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.messaging.schemas
2021-03-12 09:48:31,091 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.revocation
2021-03-12 09:48:31,105 aries_cloudagent.core.plugin_registry DEBUG Loaded module: aries_cloudagent.wallet
2021-03-12 09:48:31,119 aries_cloudagent.config.ledger INFO Fetching genesis transactions from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHempel-esatus/SSI4DE_Genesis/master/pool_transactions_genesis
2021-03-12 09:48:32,302 aries_cloudagent.core.profile INFO Create profile manager: in_memory
2021-03-12 09:48:32,311 aries_cloudagent.config.ledger INFO Ledger instance not provided
2021-03-12 09:48:32,312 aries_cloudagent.core.conductor WARNING No ledger configured

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Aries Cloud Agent ::
:: ::
:: ::
:: Inbound Transports: ::
:: ::
:: - http://0.0.0.0:8000 ::
:: ::
:: Outbound Transports: ::
:: ::
:: - http ::
:: - https ::
:: ::
:: Administration API: ::
:: ::
:: - http://0.0.0.0:11000 ::
:: ::
:: ver: 0.6.0 ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Listening...
```

Looking in the demos i just dont know why my aries can not connect to any indy-ledger.
Using indy-cli with the same genesis-files worked fine. The CLI was able to connect so i assume that all pool_genesis_files where correct.

Am i doing something wrong or is something missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finaly found the solution. The Story how i found it:

**Short Story:**

Prerequisites: Install indy-sdk, aries-cloudagent, python3_indy and python 3.6.9+ on your machine. See the long story if you don´t know how to do that.
Python 3.6.9 comes out of the box with Ubuntu18LTS

1. install aries-cloudagent-python (aca-py) localy.
2. run aca-py first with the provision command to config your aca-py instance. Use the argument wallet-type indy for that
3. run aca-py normaly with the start command and your config-params. Be sure to use the --wallet-type indy flag to be able to connect to an indy ledger

**Long Story:**

Inside the aries-cloudagent-python (aca-py) code, it seems that the configuration, which ledger to use (e.g. an indy ledger) comes from the specified wallet type.

1st.: providing arguments: --wallet-type indy
-> this returned the error, that --wallet-name and --wallet-key parameters are needed. So i provided them:

```
./scripts/run_docker start 
-e http://127.0.0.1:8000 
-it http 127.0.0.1 8000 
-ot http
--admin 127.0.0.1 11000
--admin-insecure-mode
--log-level DEBUG
--genesis-url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHempel-esatus/SSI4DE_Genesis/master/pool_transactions_genesis 
--trace 
--recreate-wallet 
--wallet-type indy 
--wallet-name test 
--wallet-key 12345
```

2nd.: This results in the following error, telling that no Database for the wallet is provided.

```
2021-03-16 09:19:45,447 indy.libindy DEBUG _indy_loop_callback: >>> command_handle: 0, err , args: (0,)
2021-03-16 09:19:45,447 indy.libindy WARNING _indy_loop_callback: Function returned error 
2021-03-16 09:19:45,449 indy.libindy DEBUG _indy_loop_callback <<<
2021-03-16 09:19:45,449 aries_cloudagent.commands.start ERROR Exception during startup:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/indy/aries_cloudagent/indy/sdk/wallet_setup.py", line 169, in open_wallet
    credentials=json.dumps(self.wallet_access),
  File "/home/indy/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/indy/wallet.py", line 127, in open_wallet
    open_wallet.cb)
indy.error.WalletNotFoundError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/indy/aries_cloudagent/commands/start.py", line 72, in init
    await startup
  File "/home/indy/aries_cloudagent/commands/start.py", line 28, in start_app
    await conductor.setup()
  File "/home/indy/aries_cloudagent/core/conductor.py", line 91, in setup
    self.root_profile, self.setup_public_did = await wallet_config(context)
  File "/home/indy/aries_cloudagent/config/wallet.py", line 40, in wallet_config
    profile = await mgr.open(context, profile_cfg)
  File "/home/indy/aries_cloudagent/indy/sdk/profile.py", line 161, in open
    opened = await indy_config.open_wallet()
  File "/home/indy/aries_cloudagent/indy/sdk/wallet_setup.py", line 182, in open_wallet
    ) from x_indy
  File "/home/indy/aries_cloudagent/indy/sdk/wallet_setup.py", line 169, in open_wallet
    credentials=json.dumps(self.wallet_access),
  File "/home/indy/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/indy/wallet.py", line 127, in open_wallet
    open_wallet.cb)
aries_cloudagent.core.error.ProfileNotFoundError: Wallet 'test' not found: Error: Wallet not found
  Caused by: No wallet database exists
```

3rd.: The documentation of aca-py at https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-cloudagent-python/blob/main/DevReadMe.md explicitly says:

> Running Locally: For local development, we recommend using the provided Docker scripts to run the ACA-Py software

4th.: aca-py is able to use sqlite, which is installed in the docker container. To see that aca-py is compatible with sqlite, run

`./scripts/run_docker start --help`

which returns the list of available arguments. One is the following:

```
--wallet-storage-type <storage-type>
                        Specifies the type of Indy wallet backend to use.
                        Supported internal storage types are 'basic' (memory),
                        'default' (sqlite), and 'postgres_storage'. The
                        default, if not specified, is 'default'. [env var:
                        ACAPY_WALLET_STORAGE_TYPE]
```

5th: Running

```
./scripts/run_docker provision 
-e http 
--genesis-url 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHempel-esatus/SSI4DE_Genesis/master/pool_transactions_genesis 
--recreate-wallet 
--wallet-type indy 
--wallet-name test 
--wallet-key 12345
```

returns

```
Successfully tagged aries-cloudagent-run:latest
Created new profile
Profile backend: indy
Profile name: test
No public DID
Ledger configured
```

This is weird, because now he is able to find sqlite. This seems to configure the Database properly so it can be used. But because it is inside a docker container, and the container discarding every change, this internal configuration will never be available.

6th. To solve this, i´ve installed on an Ubuntu18LTS the aries cloud-agent package localy from https://pypi.org/project/aries-cloudagent/

```
pip3 install aries-cloudagent
pip3 install python3_indy
```

and followed the installation instructions for the indy-sdk https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk

I also installed sqlite on the local machine with:

```
sudo apt install sqlite
```

7th.: After i rebooted the system, i executed:

```
aca-py provision -e http://127.0.0.1:8000 --genesis-url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHempel-esatus/SSI4DE_Genesis/master/pool_transactions_genesis --recreate-wallet --wallet-type indy --wallet-name test --wallet-key test
```

returning

```
Created new profile
Profile backend: indy
Profile name: test
No public DID
Ledger configured
```

8th.: After that, i cloud run aca-py and connect to my ledger using the admin-REST-api

[image]